# Import non-TypeScript files into TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to import a non-TypeScript file from `node_modules` into TypeScript.

I am using a library, which by default pulls a file of the web. The library also bundles the same file in the node module itself. So I tried importing the file into TypeScript, and was brought with a compiler error in my editor.

```
Cannot find module 'wasmoon/dist/glue.wasm' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

(wasmoon is the name of the library)

I can confirm that this file exists in `node_modules`. Why can't I import this file into TypeScript, and how can I fix it?

The import:

```js
import * as lueGlueWasm from "wasmoon/dist/glue.wasm"
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm working on a desktop app. For one, I don't want it pulling the file off the web because, well, it's a desktop app. And two, launch times are slow because it has to pull the file of the web.

Comment: Typescript tells you: the package doesn't have types. You can use `@ts-expect-error` to ignore the error.

Comment: `.wasm` is not a javascript/typescript file and cant be imported like one. Is there a reason you are not using the library as intended in [its documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasmoon)? It seems to already have types

Comment: @about14sheep please check this issue: https://github.com/ceifa/wasmoon/issues/76. In the PR linked, this is the approach taken. The way the lib works is that it expects this `.wasm` file. Like so: `const lua = new LuaEngine(luaGlueWasm)`.

Comment: about14sheep is correct, you can't do that, not in JS/TS. You will need to use a bundler plugin that deals with wasm files. Like https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-wasm. Or webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm-module-webpack-plugin. You will probably still have to tell the compiler to ignore that line.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm using `vite-plugin-wasm` and got this error: `[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "a" from "..\node_modules\wasmoon\dist\glue.wasm". Does the file exist?`

Comment:  no clue. Does it?

Comment: @JaredSmith yes I checked, the file exists.